# Formatting bash with listings

Tags: formatting, listings, linux, sourcecode, bash

I writing a documentation in LaTeX about Linux Bash resp. Shell script. And I'm having some problems:

- How can I start a formatting at the beginning of a line?
- How can I format between two signs, but only if both signs are in the same line (like: <>)?
- How can I format from a minus to a space **or** the end of the line (not to the next line)?

Here a pic:

[image]

and the code in a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}

\lstset{ %
    basicstyle=\ttfamily\footnotesize,
    commentstyle=\color{ForestGreen},
    frame=single,
    keywordstyle=\color{RoyalBlue},
    language=Bash,
    showstringspaces=false,
    %morekeywords={blue},
    morestring=[s][\color{Gray}]{<}{>},
    morestring=[s][\color{OrangeRed}]{\ -}{\ },
    morestring=[s][\color{OrangeRed}]{*}{\ },
    morestring=[s][\color{OrangeRed}]{|}{\ },
    morestring=[s][\color{OrangeRed}]{\&}{\ },
}

\begin{document}

Every time:
\begin{enumerate}
    \item the first string in a line: blue
    \item after a minus \enquote{-} (including itself), which followed a space, the string gets: red
    \item special signs \enquote{* | \&}: red
    \item after a hash \enquote{\#} (including itself): the complete line green
    \item between less/greater than \enquote{<>} (including itself): gray
    \item if a string starts with a slash \enquote{/}: this string black
    \item the rest: black
\end{enumerate}

\begin{lstlisting}
blue -red text
blue -red text  # green ...
blue-blue <gray>
blue * black    # green ...
blue -red <gray>
# green ...
/black/black/ blue -red 
blue -red /black/black/
blue -red black-black
blue black > black
blue black < black
blue -red && black -red <gray> || black -red
/black/black/ blue
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```